# confused on taylor expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

i am confused on the following thing.

Consider $f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 +x^3 + ...$, now this is a G.P and converges only for $|x|<1$, so $f(x) = 1/(1-x)$ for $|x|<1$.

On the other hand, the taylor expansion of $1/(1-x)$ gives $f(x)$, with no conditions on $x$.

Then how are the two equivalent? i should not say "equivalent", but i hope you understand what i am asking.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say the Taylor expansion has "no conditions"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to compute a Taylor series does not mean that the series converges. Convergence has to be tested additionally. Same case happens for $\log(1-x)$ or $\log(1+x)$. Furthermore, there is even Taylor series that converge and are not equal to the value of the function. These are examples of $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ not analytical functions like the traditional one:
$$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
for $x=0$. Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) can help you clarify.

Comment: thank you, nice explanation :)